# Is it a good idea to send multiple GRE scores?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, masters, application, gre

I have two GRE scores. The first one is V149+Q169+AW4 and the second one is V159+Q170+AW3.5. I'm applying for MSCS programs in some top universities. I've heard that admission officers don't care about AW scores, but some others said AW is more important than the verbal section (even for mscs programs). I will definitely send my second score but should I also send the first one to compensate my 3.5 AW in the second time? Some universities have the policy to accept the highest scores from each section. But I'm also worried that my 149 verbal score in the first time will hurt me if I send both.

Please help. Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that sending the second one would make any difference. The ETS seems to consider a 3.5 and a 4.0 on the AW test as nearly equivalent.

https://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/prepare/analytical_writing/score_level_descriptions/

Assuming this is the US, the GRE scores are only a small part of any decision in any case.

At the moment, also, coronavirus is making the GRE both less useful and less used.

Comment: I would add to that, it also depends on the field, Verbal outside social sciences is less important.

Comment: Just curious as to why the corona virus is making GRE less useful and used?

Comment: @HermanToothrot People aren't able to take it.

Comment: @Herman Toothrot: Less used because fewer people are able to travel to take the GRE, and many testing dates in the previous few months were canceled. Less useful because of the [irrelevant variance](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22irrelevant+variance%22) effect on not reporting a score being heavily influenced by factors that used to not be present (travel issues, taking care of sick family members, having to self-isolate if exposed, deemphasis in the role played by the scores in admissions, etc.).